# Interpretation of output of bounding box annotation job

Tags: amazon-web-services, bounding-box, amazon-sagemaker, labeling

The output folder of an annotation job contains the following file structure:

- active learning
- annotation-tools
- annotations
- intermediate
- manifests

Each line of the manifests/output/output.manifest file is a dictionary, where the key 'jobname' contains information about the annotations, and the key 'jobname-metadata' contains confidence score and other information about each of the bounding box annotations. There is also another folder called annotations which contain json files which contain information about annotations and associated worker ids. How are the two annotation informations related to each other? Is there any blogs/tutorials which discuss how to interpret the data received from amazon sagemaker ground-truth service? Thanks in advance.

Links I referred to: 
1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-data-output.html
2. https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/ground_truth_object_detection_tutorial/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

I have displayed the annotations received using the code available in the link 2 [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/ground_truth_labeling_jobs/ground_truth_object_detection_tutorial/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb), which treats consolidated annotations and worker response separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question. I’m the product manager for Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth and am happy to answer your question here.

We have a feature called annotation consolidation that takes the responses from multiple workers for a single image and then consolidates those responses into a single set of bounding boxes for the image. The bounding boxes referenced in the manifest file are the consolidated responses whereas what you see in the annotations folders are the raw annotations (which is why you have the respective worker IDs).

You can find out more about the annotation consolidation feature here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-annotation-consolidation.html

Please let us know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!